# Getting images from Firebase storage

Tags: json, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to get images from `Firebase` storage. I gotta get the image that is exactly the same name as the `JSON` has key value `"Product":"some name"`.

For example the image name must be like this inside the `url`:

```
let productImageref = productsValue[indexPath.row]["Product"] as? String
```

How I can get the right `url`? I don't understand it. I read all docs and as I understand I gotta use the "Download URL" from Firebase. For getting image I am using the "**KingFish**" 3rd party library to do it asynchronously.

I tried like this but it is not giving me the image:

```
let productImageref = productsValue[indexPath.row]["nicotine"] as? String

cell!.imageView!.kf_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/snuspedia.appspot.com/o/Catch%20Dry%20Eucalyptus%20White%20Mini.png?alt=media&token=68cf4b76-e35b-4868-80f3-d29872e00122")!, placeholderImage: nil)
```

Like this above code I can get image to load but I gotta load different image on every `cell`.

What I am doing wrong? Any tip is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it pretty much right but a little wrong :D

This is the code which worked like a charm:

```
let productImageref = productsValue[indexPath.row]["Products"] as? String



FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("\(productImageref!).png").downloadURLWithCompletion({(url, error)in
        if error != nil{
            print(error)
        }else{
            (cell?.imageView)!.kf_setImageWithURL(url, placeholderImage: nil)
       }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

The GS storage URL is not a real URL you can access anytime. It could only be accessible after authentication. 
Therefore, GET HTTP call can never get an image with GS URL. 
From my experience, it's better to keep the uploaded image URL like this:

```
    let reference = storage.referenceForURL(Constant.Firebase.FIREBASE_STORAGE).child(imageNameWithDate())

    if (picture != nil)
    {
        let picData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(picture!, 0.6)
        reference.putData(picData!, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
            if error == nil {
                let link = metadata?.downloadURL()!.absoluteString
                //save this link for the image URL.
            }
    }
```

Comment: That is just a simple method what I made that returns an image name as  String based on the interval since 1970.